# IOS 11.2 Cordova Inappbrowser adds a grey block on orientation change

Tags: ios, cordova, statusbar, inappbrowser, phonegap

Iv been tasked to create and app that uses Cordova Inappbrowser.
Im using the official inappbrowser plugin and statusbar plugin. all plugins are upto date!

The issue occurs when the device's orientation is changed, a grey block appears at the top left hand side. I have used XCode's simulator and environment inspector tool to try find out whats with the grey block, with no luck it just doesn't want to be inspected. I have  tested a few devices iPhone 6 and 7+ aswell as iPad mini 4 and it still appears on the device.

My code for config.xml to hide the status bar

```
<platform name="ios">
    <config-file parent="UIStatusBarHidden" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
        <true />
    </config-file>
    <config-file parent="UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
        <true />
    </config-file>
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
```

and my inappbrowser code

```
    var url = "https://imgur.com/";
    var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no');
```

My first though was that issues was related to the URL being used in inappbrowser, but i have tested a few sites and each produced the same result.

Im using statusbar plugin to hide the status bar, which works.

[image: App on Start up. no grey block]

and heres when on orientation change notice the grey block.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Adding this to CVDInAppBrowser.m, within the CDVInAppBrowserNavigationController implementation, does the trick:

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    CGRect frame = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame;
    [_bgToolbar setFrame:CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, size.width, frame.size.height)];
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
}
```

The variable _bgToolbar is the one initialized in the viewDidLoad method.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you clarify how the _bgToolbar in the viewDidLoad method is supposed to work, I only have a variable bgToolbar in that method, is the other one meant to be a reference, perhaps can you add your viewDidLoad method?  Thank you in advance

Comment: JOVAZ's answer indeed works.  You will have to add the private property _bgToolbar in  CVDInAppBrowser.m like this:

    `@interface CDVInAppBrowserWithShareButtonNavigationController : 
    UINavigationController {
        @private
        UIToolbar *_bgToolbar;
    }`

Also, you will need to add the following line in viewDidLoad:
    `bgToolbar = bgToolbar;`

Answer (score 2):

As I will never be using the status bar I set the height of the bar to 0 at the top of `CVDInAppBrowser.m`

```
#define    STATUSBAR_HEIGHT 0 // 21.0
```